# What is a good file format for saving game data?

Tags: java, file-format, xml, data, file

I need to save some custom game data.  Map, player, etc.

All of them will have "sub objects".  For example,  a map and map will have an "array" of tiles.  ie, hierarchical data.  Hopefully nothing binary.

What would be a good format for these?

So far I'ved considered:

**Serailization:** This is FAST and easy, but tends to break when I change the underlying classes :(

**XML:** I really hate parsing this.  My test case was over 100+ lines of code and seemed likes tons of "busy work" for even a very simple format.

**INI:** would be really clumsy for hierarchical data.

**Protobuf:** Never used it, but read you have to do a lot of manual mucking around and breaks if you change the class.

**Other options?** That's why I'm here!

Edit: this is Java btw.

Edit 2:

I settled on "Controlled Binary Serialization" (see below).

Pros:

- it's fast
- it's small (on disk) and can be easily compressed/decompressed during read/write.
- it's super easy to read/write from game and toolset.
- I can decide what to include/exclude of the object.
- Objects/Data can be nested.

Cons:

- Can't edit it by hand (like XML, YAML, etc)
- Can't easily read/modify it with scripts
- Java Serialization by default is pretty slow/bloated compared to other implentations, but it's stable and works

Comment: comma separated values

Comment: @trinithis KISS is a great thing.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap that thinking CSV parsing is easy: http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp

Comment: Funny, ProtoBuf was built to support upgradeability.

Comment: ini for everything user-modifiable like settings, etc; and binary for everything else.

Comment: @user697111 And to support multiple versions of GameState without breaking the game, [see this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/120073/60136)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To display hierachical data, [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)  or [JSON](http://www.json.org/) would be good options. They are *far* simpler and easier to parse than XML.

Another option would be a "controlled" binary serialization process. Every object writes it's state out in a controlled way, i.e.

```
void player::save(savegame &sgm)
{
    sgm.write(this->position);
    sgm.write(other properties);
    inventory.save(sgm);
}
```

id Tech 4 (Quake 4 / Doom 3 engine) uses such an approach.

Comment: +1 For "controlled" binary serialization.  I use this at work and it's great!

Comment: Another +1 for "controlled" binary serialization.  While I've never heard the name before, I do something similar in a few places - done right, it has the advantage of being able to set defaults for newly added fields that don't exist in the data file, and to ignore "junk" in the data file when a field is removed from the model.

Comment: I use something like this in my game. It works well! I use java. Each object has a ToByteStream method that writes to a file stream and a constructor that reads from a file stream. I didn't like Javas Serializable implementation.

Comment: Or you could just use Boost.Serialize and get wonderful features like versioning and so forth.

Comment: @Izkata I've made that name up because I have no idea how this method is called.

Comment: @RaphaelR. - Oh.  Well, I guess I'll avoid that name, then, and just describe it when needed  =P  (I know "pickling" is close, but AFAIK pickling would break if any fields change)

Comment: I like to mix JSON for ease of use with the controlled approach.

Comment: Using such a simple binary format can be an issue in the future if you need to change what is serialized (eg: adding new fields). Some players might already have old savegames that will need to be converted. Because of this, you should always include a file version at the top of your savegame. You might also use more robust methods (eg : by saving the name of the field along with the value itself). You don't have to use a string you can also use an index (like in protobuf)

Answer (score 10):

A well made binary format has really got all the advantages, it's fast, reasonably small, and as flexible as you make it.

Making a binary format you are bound by no rules, which is a great advantage, but ironically it's largely what has given binary file structures a bad name. XML, JSON and the like makes a lot of decisions for you, they are far from always optimal, but they are reasonably safe choices that will usually help you steer clear of some otherwise common problems.

Identify these problems, design your format with those in mind, and you can make a great binary format.

If you are not experienced/confident enough to make a binary format and the amount of data is small enough that the speed impact will be negligible, I suggest that you use JSON, it's simple, but does the job.

Answer (score 8):

Your choice of file format is hugely dependent on your current **toolset** and the **game** you are intending to make. With that said...

Toolset is one of the most important factors when deciding a game file format. If you make a **binary format**, you have to always ensure that you **have the tools** to input your game data. This could be as simple as a hex editor, or as complex as Unreal Editor.

I guess the main advantage of XML, YAML, or any other language files, is that you **can edit it easily** via a text editor. And using an existing standard, it **ensures you can't go wrong**. But, this is **extremely tedious** when you have a thousand files, which brings me to my next point.

Game. *What kind of game are you making?* Why I say this will affect the file format? Because, if you are making something like 2D bomberman, you **could get away with a simple text file** like:

```
*********
*1     2*    1,2,3,4  - start point of players 1, 2, 3, 4
* + + + *    *        - walls
*       *    +        - crates
* + + + *
*3     4*
*********
```

In other words, **always go for the most obvious format for your specific data**. *RPGs are the most complex* game genre to make. They require lots of data. But *doesn't mean you have to stick a specific format*, be it binary or text-based for all data in the game.

- **Maps, particles, and other graphical stuff** tend to use a custom binary format. Because it's the *simplest way to implement* it. It's not humanly-sane to describe maps textually. Usually edited via map/level/particle editors.
- Players, items, enemies, skills and quests are **statistics that affect game balance**. They usually require lots and lots of input and tweaking. I like to do this by putting it in an XML file for ease of implementation, but yet having an object editor for the designers to play with. *Best of both worlds*.

Generally, you want to describe text with a text format, and graphics with a binary format. The following should give you an example:

```
<Skill>
    <Name>Fireball</Name>
    <Animation>fireball.dat</Animation> <!-- Graphics described in another file -->
    <Attack>1.3</Attack>
    <Cooldown>15</Cooldown>
</Skill>
```

To sum it up, it is to my fullest recommendation that if possible, you don't script your data, **unless absolutely necessary**. The end-user doesn't care about how awesome the format is, as long as the game is playable, that's all that matters.

Cheers, roy =)

Answer (score 5):

BSON is pretty nice.  http://bsonspec.org/.  It is easier to parse then JSON and better at containing binary data, but still has a nice structure.  It's somewhat similar to protocol buffers.  The downside is that there dosent seem to be a lot of tool support for it outside of mongodb.

EDIT: MsgPack ( http://msgpack.org/ ) is also similar to BSON and seem to be gaining more traction.

Comment: While I think that the idea of a "binary JSON" is good I have little faith in BSON, there are too many (redundant) data types, and the documentation sucks.

Answer (score 2):

What's happened to your custom binary data format? If you are afraid of raw serialisation, write your own system that writes fields as needed, and reads them back. No need for xml, which is indeed overly bulky and complex for situations where you don't need the transparency the format provides. Just define a well-specified file format and stick to it, leaving maybe some room for expansion of your data set in each record by padding them with null values (say you have a 100 byte record now, pad that to 150 for future use.
Add a version number and maybe a checksum so you can know what fields should be filled and have a sanity check for validity, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix XML or some other format with Base64 insertions for some specific data, and for fields you need readability you can use usual TEXT